# Create stacked icon using font awesome in Qt

Tags: c++, qt5, font-awesome

Does anyone have experience with QtAwesome? I want to create stacked icons for use in my project but I can't find anything online on how to do so. Any reference to documentation or a guide will also be beneficial. I found documentations online for the QtAwesome Python library, but couldn't find any related to the C++ version.

Comment: As posted this is not a question about programming (no code posted) and more about how to search for a solution and thus out of scope for this site.  Please post what you have tried and we can perhaps help you fix it.